# AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, plotly

I want to make a dropdown that displays each year of collected data for my graph but this just does not work with pandas

```
 # Variable Declaration, dataframe & Others ---------------------------------------------

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.groupby(
    ['Country Name', 'Country Code', "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009",
     "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", '2021'])



app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.JOURNAL])

title = dcc.Markdown(children='# World Population Densities By Country')
subtitle = dcc.Markdown(children='*Data taken from [The World Bank](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EN.POP.DNST)*')
mygraph = dcc.Graph(figure={})

dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(options=df.columns.values[2:],#this line is the issue
                        value='2021',
                        clearable=False)

# Layout -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Idk why this happens but it gives me the error `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'columns'`
Ive searched all over stackoverflow but none of the things i found matched with what i did nor worked for me when i tried.

Comment: You need to convert the data frame from wide format to long format. `df.melt(id_vars=['Country Name','Country Code'],value_vars=df.columns[2:], var_name='year')`

Comment: never heard of `df.melt()`, probably wouldnt ever have oherwise as well so, i guess this comment really helped out clear a long standing issue